# COPYFILE post MSI Installation Using WIX

Tags: xml, installation, wix

Please see below statements; for time being I have hard coded source and destination folders (this folders are formed during Installation process) in setup project of MSI. Note: Below file paths are the one where MSI package installation destination are and not the source location from. The question how to set the destination or source property values by hiding the hard coded values like [INSTALLLOCATION]\App_Config\

As of now I am passing INSTALLLOCATION (E:\Websites\SCBUDirect\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb) through command line and want to set the Destination folder value as [INSTALLLOCATION]\App_Config\ but not sure how it can be implemented through property setting or custom actions which I tried but failed to make it work.

Below is the Snippet (from heat.exe) of component of the file which need to be copied .

```
<Component Id="cmp209B0DBB82F9FF15193D29F0BD337B7F" Directory="dirB0A921E55A598C65B18B4E47885629C3" Guid="{3B140259-FCC7-4D2E-8629-CBB879BBA46C}">
  <File Id="filBC5CC5B8DCC504F6DC75A7B2673E7D0D" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Workspaces\Chatra\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config\basic.log4net.dev" />
</Component>
```

Here is my part of my code in product.wxs

```
<Fragment>
    <Property Id="SourceFilesFolder" Value="E:\Websites\SCBUDirect\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config\basic.log4net.dev" />

    <Property Id="DestFilesFolder" Value="E:\Websites\SCBUDirect\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config\" />


  <ComponentGroup Id="CopyFiles">
         <ComponentRef Id="CMP_LOG4TXT" />
    </ComponentGroup>

      <Component Id="CMP_LOG4TXT" Guid="341BD660-7249-42DD-9744-DBEF0776AD52"  Directory="INSTALLLOCATION" KeyPath="yes">
        <CopyFile Id="Copy_LOG4TXT" 
              SourceProperty="SourceFilesFolder" 
              DestinationProperty="DestFilesFolder" 
              DestinationName="basic.log4net" />
      </Component>

</Fragment>
```

Comment: I would start by running the msi using `msiexec /i yourProduct.msi /lvoicewarmupx log.txt` and then search the resulting log.txt for the Component's Id and Guid to see if it gives you any helpful information.

Comment: `CopyFile` does not copy a file until the `InstallExecuteSequence`

Comment: Hi now I was able to figure what was the problem ,I have not specified the copy component in feature. But now I don't want to hard code the source and destination. Is it possible to do that. As of now I am passing INSTALLLOCATION (E:\Websites\SCBUDirect\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb) through command line and want to set the Destination folder value as [INSTALLLOCATION]\App_Config\ but not sure how it can be implemented through property setting or custom actions which I tried but failed to make it work.

Comment: Natalie Carr, Can you give some more details on InstallExcuteSequence ? and how the solution for this action would look like. And also I have modified the Question also to be clear on it

Comment: Use `SetProperty` to set the destination property.     <SetProperty Id="DESTFILESFOLDER" Value="[INSTALLLOCATION]App_Config" After="LaunchConditions"></SetProperty>

Comment: Natalie Carr "SetProperty" helped and also setting parameter  [INSTALLLOCATION]  as "E:\Websites\SCBUDirect" which is passed as argument helped   but their was problem during Uninstall .Given me error "Network search "\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config" could not be found" . Seams like [INSTALLLOCATION] value not getting stored for Uninstall. What could be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

you can use relative path like so:

```
<Component Id="comp_Include_0" DiskId="1" KeyPath="yes" Guid="D026AE84-0F34-4715-810D-4EB6656DFECD">
    <File Id="file_Include_0" Source="..\Include\3rdParty\ac_types2.6\ac_complex.h" />
</Component>
```

the "..\" 
means for example the bin\release folder 
it's declared like this :

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder">
      <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="ATE" >
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Directory>
```

you will need to declare

```
<DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
```

the easiest way I have found to create wix installer is to use paraffin for full directories

Answer (score 0):

[INSTALLLOCATION] File path's  Pattern Saving need to be done here ,So that file path is saved during Installation and Uninstall. Otherwise we get Network Search errors.

```
<product>

    <Property Id="INSTALLLOCATION">
          <RegistrySearch Id="REMEMBERPROPERTY" Root="HKCU" Key="Websites\SCBUDirect" Name="Remembered" Type="raw"/> 
    </Property>

        <CustomAction Id="SAVEINSTALLDIR" Property="CMDREMEMBERPROPERTY" Value="[INSTALLLOCATION]"/>
        <CustomAction Id="SETINSTALLDIR" Property="INSTALLLOCATION" Value="[CMDREMEMBERPROPERTY]" />

        <InstallExecuteSequence>
          <Custom Action="SAVEINSTALLDIR" Before="AppSearch"></Custom>
         <Custom Action="SETINSTALLDIR" After="AppSearch">CMDREMEMBERPROPERTY</Custom>
        </InstallExecuteSequence>

        <SetProperty Id="DestFilesFolder" Value="[INSTALLLOCATION]\Website\App_Config" After="CostInitialize" />

</product>

<fragment>

  <ComponentGroup Id="CopyFiles">
         <ComponentRef Id="CMP_LOG4TXT" />
    </ComponentGroup>

      <Component Id="CMP_LOG4TXT" Guid="341BD660-7249-42DD-9744-DBEF0776AD52"  Directory="dir572C565E70B3AEE6F0C29D3EE9056E9B" KeyPath="yes">
        <CopyFile Id="Copy_LOG4TXT"         Source="E:\Websites\SCBUDirect\Website\SCBUDirect.B2CWeb\App_Config\basic.log4net.dev" DestinationProperty="DestFilesFolder" DestinationName="basic.log4net" />
      </Component>

</fragment>
```